# Issues with Converting Upper to Lower Case in Java (Could it be memory location issues?)

Tags: java, sorting, heap-memory, uppercase, lowercase

I am writing a program that will convert the naming into standard naming convention. 
For example, (aLeX teReNce = Alex Terence) and another example, (kImBerLy tAn > Kimberly Tan) I have successfully converted it but when it comes to comparison, the program will fail. Can I please know what are the issues here? And also any other way to solve it? Is there any alternative way other than toUpper and toLower?

Could this be something has to do with memory location? Because when I change aLeX teReNce to aLeX teRaNce I get some strange symbol there where it seems like the program is displaying address of memory

Thank You!

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String searchName = "aLeX teReNce";

        String[] str = searchName.split(" ");

        searchName = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            searchName += toUpper(str[i].charAt(0));

            for(int j = 1; j < str[i].length(); j++)
            {
                searchName += toLower(str[i].charAt(j));
            }

            searchName += " ";
        }

        searchName = searchName.trim();

        System.out.println("After Rearrange: " + searchName);
        System.out.println();

        if(searchName.equals("Alex Terence"))
        {
            System.out.println("True");
        }

    }

    public static char toUpper(char upper)
    {
        if(!(upper > 'A' && upper < 'Z'))
        {
            upper = (char)((int)(upper) - 32);
        }

        return upper;
    }

    public static char toLower(char lower)
    {
        if(!(lower > 'a' && lower < 'z'))
        { 
            lower = (char)((int)(lower) + 32);
        }

        return lower;
    }
```

Comment: `searchName` ends up with a white space at the last position.

Comment: But when I display searchName, it does come out Alex Terence as I expected. The problem is that when I Check it with “Alex Terence” in the if statement, it won’t go into it

Comment: Because there's a white space in the end of `searchName`. Add a white space after `Alex Terence` and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of a trailing whitespace at the end.
After completing the inner for loop for `Terence`, it is adding an additional whitespace at the end. So your string is `"Alex Terence "` not `"Alex Terence"`
After the outer for loop trim the string like this to remove the trailing whitespace.

```
searchName = searchName.trim()
```

An alternative approach to prevent this from happening in the first place would be to use the static `join()` method of the String class.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String searchName = "aLeX teReNce";

        String[] str = searchName.split(" ");

        searchName = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            searchName += toUpper(str[i].charAt(0));

            for(int j = 1; j < str[i].length(); j++)
            {
                searchName += toLower(str[i].charAt(j));
            }

            str[i] = searchName;
        }

        searchName = String.join(" ", str);
        System.out.println("After Rearrange: " + searchName);
        System.out.println();

        if(searchName.equals("Alex Terence"))
        {
            System.out.println("True");
        }

    }
```

EDIT:
You're getting the strange symbol because there's an error in both your `toUpper()` and `toLower()` methods.
It won't give you the right output if you have an a/A or z/Z in your name because you have stated the conditon as `upper<A` and `upper>Z`which doesn't include A/a and Z/z. Change it to:

```
upper >= 'A' && upper <= 'Z'
lower >= 'a' && lower <= 'z'
```

What's happening is the `a` in `teRaNce` is passed to the `toLower()` method. Since it is already lowercase it shouldn't be converted but a and z were not included in your condition and hence it qualifies to be converted which adds 32 to `a` which gives you the character corresponding to 129.

Comment: I tried it and it is working. Try printing out the value of `searchName.compareTo("Alex Terence")`, just for debugging purposes. And did you try the alternative approach?

Comment: Yes I did as well. And also I have updated the question, could you please identify the issue here?

Comment: I got -19 for searchName.compareTo("Alex Terence")

Comment: Check out my update in the answer to your updated question.